# SHA256 encoding in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, parameters, sha256

I am struggling with SHA256 encoding.

There is a Python example but I don't understand it quite well.
Example (Python):

```
message = nonce + client_id + api_key
signature = hmac.new(API_SECRET, msg=message, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper()
```

Can somebody make a simple blueprint so I can work from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) implements SHA256

If you include the library, you should be able to run the following (assuming 'message' and 'API_SECRET' are the same as the python code)

```
var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(message,API_SECRET).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex).toUpperCase();
```